# SQL: Select an item in one column based on the other column's value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-----+----+
|A    |B   |
+-----+----+
|    1|   0|
|    2|   1|
|    2|   1|
|    2|   1|
|    2|   2|
|    3|   1|
|    4|   1|
|    5|   1|
|    5|   2|
|    6|   2|
|    7|   2|
|    8|   2|
+-----+----+
```

I want to select values of A, where the value of B is the lowest. but want to keep the repetitions. Say I have 3 pairs such that (4,5),(4,5),(4,6), I want the result to be (4,5), (4,5).

For the above table, I would like the output to be

```
+-----+----+
|A    |B   |
+-----+----+
|    1|   0|
|    2|   1|
|    2|   1|
|    2|   1|
|    3|   1|
|    4|   1|
|    5|   1|
|    6|   2|
|    7|   2|
|    8|   2|
+-----+----+
```

I was trying to do something like this, but I'm lost!

```
SELECT t1.A, t1.B from table t1 JOIN table t2
WHERE t1.B >= t2.B
ORDER BY B DESC
```

Any leads appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select t1.* from mytable t1
join
    (select A, min(B) as B from mytable group by A) t2
on t1.A = t2.A and t1.B = t2.B
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is the 't' at the very end?

Comment: I fixed it, it was a typo.

Comment: I was wondering if this would work -  SELECT A, min(B) as B from table group by A

Comment: It looks like a new question. If it is, please open a new question. My answer doesn't make sense anymore.

Comment: I changed the example for clarification. Your answer seems to work for me. I'm sorry, but why do you think your answer doesn't make sense? Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: my answer is good but you changed the data and there are no more duplicates in the sample. might be confusing. Anyways feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: Oh right, my bad! Have included duplicates and have accepted your answer! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
a.A, a.B
FROM table1 a WHERE B=(select MIN(b) FROM table1)
ORDER BY B DESC
```

Comment: This only gives the correct answer because it happens to be that both mins are = 1, but with more data it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subquery. First identify all the columns that are satisfying the condition. Then filter out the records using where.

```
select A,B from(
        select A,B, case when B<A then 'Y' else 'N' end as C from table)
        where C = 'Y'
```